# Node-Red compare new and previous values

Tags: node-red

I'm new to Node-Red and I don't know if that's possible without some storage (SQL database for example).

[image]

So, I have an MQTT endpoint that pushes numeric value when update made.
For example - message.payload = 799.
What I want is on every new message compare this new value with the previous one (the one that was received right before) without any external storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Report By Exception (RBE) node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-rbe). This will only allow a value to pass if it is different from the previous value (it can be used with multiple inputs and uses the `msg.topic` to distinguish between variables to track).

You can also use the [Context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) to store values. There are multiple levels of context that are available at different scopes to allow you to store and share information between nodes.